# MessageBox.show() is it not safe to call in worker thread?

Tags: winforms

In a C# winform app, I have a background worker in the doWork method deep down the stack tree an object is calling

```
            // This is ok to be called on non UI thread because 
            // MessageBox has its own message pump
            result = MessageBox.Show(form, message, AppStrings.low_space_title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

The comments are from a previous developer, and this code apparently worked, now it seems to be not working any more.. the error that I am getting is

```
   Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FormMain' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

Any help would be appreciated to resolve this

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageBox` is ok to be called from a different thread **only** if you are not assigning the main form (which was created on the UI thread, and is therefore bound to it) as the `IWin32Window` that owns the `Messagebox`.

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y.aspx) overload instead:

```
result = MessageBox.Show(message, AppStrings.low_space_title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```